# get file path for uri.parse() in android

Tags: android, file, path, location, uri

I have the location of a file,

D:\Android\WorkSpace\myApp\res\drawable-hdpi\image.PNG

how can I get the file path to use inside uri.parse()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the path to your URI path like as follows.may be in two ways:

```
1.Uri path=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/" + R.drawable.image);
2. Uri path=uri.parse("android.resource://"+PACKAGE_NAME+"/"+"drawable/image"
```

Comment: I'm using this for sending the image as an attachment with an email. but this doesn't work

Comment: It's easier to use getPackageName() function to get the package name. see my own answer to this question.

Comment: @Mona Thanks.I did not have knowledge of that...+1 to ur answer :)

Comment: i am working on the same problem; the image is sent but it has no extension. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: @WildThing is it in drawable folder ? if it is not working then you may think of renaming it programmatically.

Comment: @AndroidKiller Yes it is in the drawable folder, for instance when i try to share it using GMAIL, it is attached and named 2130837559 (with no extension)

Comment: @WildThing in name you can just change the name programmatically.

Comment: @AndroidKiller the intent is based on the uri, so how can you change the name programmatically without altering the URI?

Answer (score 6):

I found it much easier to use "getPackageName()" method. so here is what worked for me,

```
 Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.image));
```